# how can I send requests to facebook test users?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have created a number of test user accounts. How can I send requests to these test users since they don't appear in the list of friends?

Answer (score 2):

You can only send Requests from one Testuser to another Testuser. And you can create friend connections between the Testusers in the App Settings.

Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users

Answer (score 0):

You need to know all the testers. I mean You have to have these people in your list friends

Answer (score 0):

For the test accounts you make in app page '5 max', you need to add the test users to each other using a button next to each user.

Then using any of them you can send a request to any other test user.